# Next Js API wont resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, next.js

I'm very new to back-end development so I'd appreciate help with my following questions. I'm writing a next js app which which displays a black and white filter of an image when you upload it. In index.js, once the selected file in the input changes, it calls the image process api with a formData multipart.

**Directory**
[image]

**Index**

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Home()
{
  
  async function onFileChange(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault()
    let form = await document.getElementById("imageForm")
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    const response = await fetch(`/api/imageProcess/${formData}`)
    console.log(response)
  }

  return(
    <form id = "imageForm" encType="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <input type="file" id="imageInput" onChange={onFileChange}/>
    </form>
  )
}
```

I have two main questions. How can I extract the image url from the req so I can apply the filter to it with this function:

```
const filter = require('node-image-filter');

export default function imageProcess(req, res)
{
    let imageUrl = 0;
    filter.render(imageUrl, filter.preset.grayscale, function(result)
    {
        res.send(`${result}`);
    }); 
}
```

Second, even if I am able to extract the link, the call isn't able to resolve. For some reason this works on my node js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const filter = require('node-image-filter');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
    
app.get('/filter', function(req, res)
{
    imageUrl = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510__480.jpg'
    filter.render(imageUrl, filter.preset.grayscale, function(result)
    {
        result.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`result.${result.type}`));
        res.send('save filtered image');
    });
})

app.listen(PORT);
```

**However** it never resolves with the next.js version of my code. It takes infinite time to execute.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For an API route to work, you need to export a function as default (a.k.a request handler) as pr [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)

Change function name `imageProcess` to `handler`

Comment: The name of the function isn't relevant. As long as it's a default export the API route should work fine.